# Сравнение двух Map

Tags: java

Как сравнить два `Map`?
Например:

Дано:

```
Map<Object, Object> s1
Map<Object, Object> s2
```

В них есть значения например

```
s1[STRING(S):='TEST', INT(I)=45]

s2[STRING(S):='TEST', INT(I)=46]
```

Вывод `FALSE` потому что `S1 INT(I) <> S2 INT(I)`, если все переменные равны по значению и по названию `key` вернуть `TRUE`

Имена переменных не известны, и требуется сравнить два `MAP` по значениям, по названиям `key`.

Пример кода:

Класс TESTMODEL

```
public class TESTMODEL {
    public int a = 0;
    public int s = 0;
}
```

MAIN:

```
public static Map<Object , TESTMODEL> s1 = null;
public static Map<Object , TESTMODEL> s2 = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    s1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    TESTMODEL testS1 = new TESTMODEL();
    testS1.a = 45;
    testS1.s = 46;

    s1.put(0, testS1);


    s2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    TESTMODEL testS2 = new TESTMODEL();
    testS2.s = 46;
    testS2.a = 45;


    s2.put(0, testS2);

    boolean test = s1.equals(s2);
    if(test)System.out.println("OK");
    if(!test)System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

Вывод: FALSE

Comment: Хмм... а `equals` не решает это за вас?

Comment: Нет, он выдает всегда false даже когда должно быть true

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести код с примером вывода?

Comment: @ДенисКотляров все зависит от конкретной реализации Map (т.к. интерфейс Map может реализовать любой желающий), но для всего из основной коллекции метод `.equals()` удовлетворяет условиям: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractMap.java.html#431

Comment: Я понел что я не то делал, онже проверяет у класса TESTMODEL eguals которого попросту нету вот всегда и выходит FALSE так?

Comment: Да спасибо оказалось все верно не хватает eguals который сравнивалбы все эти классы.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, если поняли, то напишите ответ и выделите его, как правильный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось все просто, может кто-то столкнется с такойже проблемой поэтому оставляю ответ.

В классе TESTMODEL отсутствует eguals который сравнивалбы между сабой два разных TESTMODEL.

Поэтому

```
public class TESTMODEL {
public int a = 0;
public int s = 0;


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj == null)return false;
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if(((TESTMODEL)obj).a != a)return false;
    if(((TESTMODEL)obj).s != s)return false;

    return true;

}
}
```

И все будет работать как часы.

Comment: Можно еще добавить instanceof , но он как известно самый медленный в java. В случае ошибки варнинг или падение сразу.